# Input value is null instead of entered value

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel

I would like to use JqueryUI autocomplete but when I try to send a value from search input I have a null instead of entered value. In my blade file I have a form:

```
<form method="post" action="{{ route('meals.store') }}" class="container-form">
    @csrf
    <label for="date">Nazwa produktu:</label>
    <input name="product-name" type="text" id="product-name" required/>
</form>
```

In blade I added a script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $( "#product-name" ).autocomplete({
        source: function (request, response) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "add/search",
                data: {
                    term: request.term
                },
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (data) {
                    var resp = $.map(JSON.parse(data), function (obj) {
                        return {
                            label: obj.name,
                            value: obj.id
                        }
                    });
                    response(resp);
                }
            });
        },
        minLength: 2
    });
});
```

This script send a term to url 'add/search' and that route is connected with function search:

```
public function search(Request $request)
    {
        $name = $request->get('product-name');
        Debugbar::info($name);
        $result = DB::table('products')->select(array('id', 'name'))->where('name', 'LIKE', '%' . $name . '%')->limit(25)->get();
        return response()->json($result->toJson());
    }
```

But I got all results because $name variable is null even when I entered a value.

When I try to use $request->all(); I got an array with key and value `"term" => "ban"` and I don't know how is that possible when input name is other.

Comment: This is because you are making a post request and trying to get parameter. change this         $name = $request->get('product-name'); to `$request->'product_name`  or `$request->only('product_name')` and also change product-name to procductName or product_name don't use - use _ or camel case

Comment: Both solutions are not working. I changed name of input to productName. When I try to use $request->'productName' I get null as before and with using only('productName') I get empty array.

Comment: just your request `return $request->all();` and add it's output to your question

Comment: Added that. When I change a key name to term that's working but I wonder why a key is term instead of productName?

Comment: if you see in jquery script you are passing data to request body as `data: {term: request.term}` change term to product_name here or back-end change product-name to term.

Comment: Yes, that's working like I said. I changed that in jQuery and working well even when I use $request->get('productName'). You was really helpfull so if you will change your answer bellow to correct I will mark that as working answer :) Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you are making a `post request` and trying to get `route parameter`.
 change this

```
$name = $request->get('product-name');
```

to

```
$request->'product_name'
```

or

```
$request->only('product_name')
```

and also change product-name to `procductName` or `product_name` don't use `-` use `_` or `camel case`

What you are trying to do is needs to be done like below

```
http://localhost/meals/store?product-name="abc";
```

if you do like then your code will work

```
 $name = $request->get('product-name');
 return $name; // will return abc
```

Also add validation to your request like below

**Controller:**

```
public function search(Request $request)
{
        $this->validate($request, ['product_name' => 'required'])
        $name = $request->get('product-name');
        Debugbar::info($name);
        $result = DB::table('products')->select(array('id', 'name'))->where('name', 'LIKE', '%' . $name . '%')->limit(25)->get();
        return response()->json($result->toJson());
}
```

**Blade file:**

```
<form method="post" action="{{ route('meals.store') }}" class="container-form">
    @csrf
    <label for="date">Nazwa produktu:</label>
    <input name="product-name" type="text" id="product-name" required/>
    @error('email')
        <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
               <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
         </span>
    @enderror

</form>
```

One more thing if you see your `jquery script` you are passing `term as body data` having the `value` of `product-name` change this:

```
data: {
         term: request.term
 },
```

to:

```
data: {
             product_name: request.term
     },
```

or alternatively you can change `$request->product_name` in your controller to `$request->term`

Hope it helps.

Thanks